# Как создать внешнюю сторону своего кода?

Tags: kotlin, gui, ui

Я только начинаю свой путь программиста, и сейчас у меня такая ситуация: я хочу создать приложение калькулятор. Я написал код в среде intellj idea, и сейчас я хочу его визуализировать. Вопрос: Какая программа мне нужна, чтобы сделать его внешнюю сторону, чтоб он выглядел примерно так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: мобильное приложение или десктопную программу?  если моб приложение то android studio будет достаточно

Comment: Спасибо, а помимо Android Studio, какие еще есть похожие программы?

Comment: @SolarGt вообще есть другие программы, но нет смысла пытаться их использовать - AndroidStudio - официальная и поддерживаемая IDE, остальное - неофициальные варианты для любителей поизвращаться

Comment: Вам нужна не программа, а учебник. никакая программа не сделает за вас "внешнюю сторону".

Comment: Я понимаю, что никакая программа не сделает за меня "внешнюю сторону", и все придется сделать ручками. Вот я и хочу узнать, КАК и с помощью чего программисты реализовывают внешний вид своих приложений. Мобильные, десктопные программы... Android Studio тоже ведь была не всегда, а начиная с 2014 года вроде, не считая анонс в 2013. Может быть, есть какие то учебники по теме создания внешней части приложения. Буду благодарен за рекомендации.

Comment: в любом учебнике по программированию под андроид эта тема затрагивается

Comment: Если вас интересует декстоп версия, то начните с библиотеки Java Swing, очень удобно сделать простенький графический интерфейс для того же калькулятора

Comment: Начните с выбора Runtime. Ваш готовый код исполняется где? JVM? Тогда начните с UI библиотек для JVM. Из последнего: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-desktop/

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, AVRamones, спасибо большое за совет)